# ASP.NET Entity Framework API Update single column

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework and I created an API controller, now I want to add a method that is basically a copy of the put method, however I want to adjust this method so it updates a single column

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        [Authorize]
        public IHttpActionResult PutUser(int id, Users user)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != user.id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!UsersExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```

each user in my User class has an email and column called isOnline, for this method I want to update the isOnline to true based on the email.

The examples I have seen online are for non API controllers. Please Help!

Comment: The code for EF is the same whether it is an api controller or an MVC controller.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: How do I adjust this method to update one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subject is partial update in Entity Framework, following is an example:

```
var user= new User() {Id = id, TargetColumn = "test"};
context.Users.Attach(user);
var entry = context.Entry(user);
entry.Property(e => e.TargetColumn ).IsModified = true;;
```